# Create an image from png and resize

Tags: php, image, gd

I am currently working on app, part of the functionality is to take x amount of filepaths from the $_GET data, and loop through them to create one new image from then.

This is my current code,

```
<?php

$images = rtrim($_GET['images'], ",");

$images = explode(",", $images);

$img = imagecreatetruecolor(1060, 811);

// Make alpha channels work

imagealphablending($img, true);
imagesavealpha($img, true);

foreach($images as $fn) {

    // Load image
    $cur = imagecreatefrompng($fn);
    imagealphablending($cur, true);
    imagesavealpha($cur, true);

    // Copy over image
    imagecopyresampled($img, $cur, 0,0,0,0, 1060, 811, 1060, 811);

    // Free memory
    imagedestroy($cur);

}

header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($img);
```

What I want to know is how I can resize each image that created also, the images that site in my filesystem are, 2000x1539. The ideal would that get resized from the 2000x1539 to 1060x811 or even better let the resize work out the height itself to keep the aspect ratio.

I thought I would be able to use `imagecopyresized()` but sadly not.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: There must be hundreds of web pages with tutorials on how to resize images in PHP. What specifically is your problem that one of these sites wouldn’t be able to help with?

Comment: why cant you use imagecopyresized()

Comment: @user574632 it takes no account of the new image size I want.

Comment: Argh! I was sending the params in the wrong way round.